# javascript 2d array tile map srcolling

Tags: javascript, arrays, scroll

I have searched this for weeks but just can't find the right tutorial.
Lets say we have a canvas that is 800x800.

```
<canvas id='draw' width=800 height=800></canvas>
```

And we have a tile map(0 will be square barriers and 1 will be air).

```
var tileMap = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
]
```

How do I make the map scroll so that only 3x3 of the squares be seen whenever the player moves?
For example:

```
canvas screen-->           [0,0,0]
                           [0,1,1]      <-- just this part to be seen
                           [0,0,0]
```

when player moves:

```
canvas screen-->           [0,0,0]
                           [1,1,1]     <-- now this part will be seen
                           [0,0,0]
```

So how do I make the tile map move to give the illusion that the player is moving?

Comment: I really did not get your question can you explain for example?

Answer (score 1):

`tileMap` should not be modify instead you create some object that represents center of current view e.g. player and use it in your display function. Whenever you want to scroll you just **move center** of **view**.

```js
var tileMap = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
]


var hero = {
 position: {
   x: 0,
    y: 1
  }
};

const air = 1;
const barrier = 0;

display(hero,tileMap);

// move player instead of scrolling data
// tileMap is untouched
hero.position.x += 3;

display(hero,tileMap);

// use player position to display only portion of map
function display(player,map) {
  var result = [
     "",
      "",
      ""
    ];
    
    for(var y = 0, i = player.position.y - 1; y < 3; i++,y++) {
      if (i >= 0 && i < map.length) {
           for(var x = 0, j = player.position.x - 1; x < 3; j++,x++) {
                if ( j >= 0 && j < map[i].length) {
                  result[y] += map[i][j] + ",";
                }
                else {
                 // outside map only ait
                 result[y] += air+ ",";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
         // outside map only ait
         result[y] += air +","+ air +","+air+",";
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not explained how is your array correlated with your canvas and animations - therefore a clear guess is that you're concerned about your Arrays only.

You need a **viewport Array** `viewMap` dictated by the *camera* `cam` position and size values.
In the example below it's anchor is left/top (you might want to change the logic later to use center/center instead,  up to you).

- on keyboard event, change the camera `x y` position and prevent going out of map boundaries
- Populate your `viewMap` array and print it:

```js
var tileMap = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 1, 0],
  [0, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var cam = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 3,
  height: 3
};

// Create empty 2D viewMap of viewport
var viewMap = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cam.height; i++) viewMap[i] = new Array(cam.width);


function tileViewport() {
  for (var y = 0; y < cam.height; y++)
    for (var x = 0; x < cam.width; x++)
      viewMap[y][x] = tileMap[y + cam.y][x + cam.x];
  // PRINT
  console.clear(); console.log(viewMap.map(a => a.join(" ")).join("\n"))
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  
  if( /^(37|38|39|40)$/.test(key) ) e.preventDefault(); // prevent browser default stuff
  
  if (key === 38) --cam.y;
  if (key === 40) ++cam.y;
  if (key === 37) --cam.x;
  if (key === 39) ++cam.x;

  // Fix movement to tileMap area boundary
  cam.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(cam.y, tileMap.length - cam.height));
  cam.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(cam.x, tileMap[0].length - cam.width));

  tileViewport();
});

// INITIALIZE
tileViewport();
```

```html
Click here and user your keyboard arrows!
```

Now that the above works correctly you can:

- Add logic for obstacles behavior by using the new `viewMap` Array
- prefetch new tiles for your canvas,
- animate the canvas depending on the movement